# MongoDB returns different values from count() and find() for same filters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am running a MongoDB 6.0.3 replica set. I have a collection of products and I want to get the count of products matching my filters. However, when I run find(), I get about 23 results returned, but when I run count(), I get a count of 706 matching documents. What could be the issue here?

```
replicaset-01 [primary] mydb> db.products.find({company_name:"Acme", image:''}).count()
706
replicaset-01 [primary] mydb> db.products.find({company_name:"Acme", image:''}, {_id:1})
[
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490a03") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490b46") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490b0e") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490b4d") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa4909a2") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490b06") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa4909a3") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5469a8d7621aa490c52") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5469a8d7621aa490d12") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5469a8d7621aa490c98") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490949") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa4909e3") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490a80") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490b6d") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa4909eb") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490b50") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5469a8d7621aa490b93") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5459a8d7621aa490940") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5479a8d7621aa4911a1") },
  { _id: ObjectId("636bd5479a8d7621aa491070") }
]
```

Comment: [_"Executing `db.collection.find()` in mongosh automatically iterates the cursor to display up to the first **20** documents. Type `it` to continue iteration."_](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#cursor-handling)

Comment: What @rickhg12hs said. Also, you can append [.itcount()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.itcount/) to your `.find()` if you want to count the number of documents in a cursor.

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs - I feel properly silly for missing that in the docs. Please feel free to post as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your `mongosh` commands are executing as designed.

- `db.collection.find(...).count()` will provide the total document count of `find`.
- `db.collection.find(...)` will print the first **20** documents.

The perhaps surprising, and important point here (from the docs):

> [*"Executing `db.collection.find()` in `mongosh` automatically iterates
> the cursor to display up to the first **20** documents. Type `it` to
> continue
> iteration."*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#cursor-handling)